# How to design an ontology?

Tags: rdf, semantics, ontology

On a project we describe the meta data by RDF by using SIOC, FOAF, SKOS namespaces. After this step what we need to do to design an ontology for collaborate these informations?

Comment: why do you need another ontology if you've already described your data ?

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean you have decided how to describe the data, but not yet built the ontology? Protege is a powerful ontology editor and might be your best bet.